# Azure DevOps - exist only one branch

Tags: .net, azure-devops

I would like to ask you about how to display more than one branch on Azure DevOps.
I want to emphasize that everything work correctly when i open the same project on SourceTree (atlassian)
What i have (left side) and what i want (right side).

[image]

Comment: Not get your response for several days, are the answers below helpful to you? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that now on devops. It currently only displays the commit graph originating from a single branch.

You can use an extension on visual studio to accomplish this from there.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.githistory

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: After weekend I would like to tell you that @CaioGomes answer is wrong and it is possible to show more than one branch. You need to make pull request or merge from another branch.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365945/show-git-graph-with-all-branches.html this issue is known by Microsoft and they are currently working on that. This is not possible yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no `All branches` option in azure devops to display the git graph of all branches . We have added this feature to our roadmap.

Until now, in our official feature suggestion for Azure Devops forum, there has been a such suggestion exist in it: [Show git graph with all branches](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365945/show-git-graph-with-all-branches.html). You can comment and vote it there. We will keep you updated as we make progress.

Answer (score -1):

I want to tell that more than one branch is possible when you make a pull request or merge from another branch.

Comment: In fact,still display a branch , the blue dots represent any commit in the repo or a file,the grey dots represent a merge commit. A line connects a commit to its ancestor commit. You can refer to this [document](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/announcing-git-graph-and-advanced-filters-to-visualize-commit-history/) for details.